# Dashed line() in Matlab

Tags: matlab, line

Is there a way to make `line()` in MATLAB dashed rather than solid?

For example, how could I make `line([0 0], [0 10])` dashed rather than solid?

Comment: Usually, it is a lot easier and faster if you look in the MATLAB manual first, or at least google it. MATLAB documentation is quite good, and amply covers basics like these. That way, we here at SO don't have to repeat the examples that can readily be found in the manual or at the first google hit.

Comment: Yeah no worries. Would you like to me delete the question?

Comment: I googled "line() dashed matlab" and there wasn't anything helpful from the first 3 or 4 places I looked.

Comment: No don't sweat it, it's OK. But please do that for your next question, and include your findings and attempts in the quesiton itself. Interestingly, when I google that exact phrase, the first hit is the page that I linked to in my answer...but my google bubble is probably different from yours.

Comment: @lily23 https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html, https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html First links on google. try to google more general questions, like linestyle/ line properties, specifications etc

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, yeah okay thanks for the tips. I've worked out how you found it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `doc line_props`:

```
line([0 0], [0 10], 'LineStyle', '--');
```

Comment: '--' for a dashed one to be exact.